# Is using SharpDX or SlimDX easier than using DirectX directly from C++?

Tags: xna, directx, slimdx, sharpdx

I decided to learn to program in DirectX yesterday, and, not being a huge C++ fanatic, went looking for a .Net wrapper. After reading about SlimDX and SharpDX, I decided I liked what the SharpDX people were doing and began trying to use it. Although they have a huge number of samples that are really nice,  I had trouble finding any tutorials specifically for it. I ended up seeing a huge number of C++ tutorials. Besides the really long and less than aesthetically pleasing function names, it really didn't seem any more complicated than using the managed wrappers.

So my options (and what I think about them) are:

- SlimDX/SharpDX are in a language I am familiar with, but nearly as complicated as the C++
- DirectX is C++, something I am not too familiar with. I would really need to learn proper memory management.
- Focus on really learning C++ well before diving into game programming with straight Direct3D. This would allow me to learn proper memory management and get comfortable with C++.

My original thinking was that if using Direct3D was just as easy as a managed equivalent, there would be no point starting with the managed equivalent. On the other hand, if the managed equivalent is much easier, it would allow me to focus on the ins and outs of developing a game rather than constantly worrying about the language and getting even small things done.

So, will using one of these managed wrappers be easier than using the native Direct3D API itself?

Comment: It totally doesn't make sense to ask whether to use SharpDX/SlimDX or DirectX. That's becaus SharpDX/SlimDX are thin wrappers around DirectX. They expose almost exact same API as native C++ API to managed world. It's like asking - do you drive to work automobile or Honda.

Comment: That is a fairly good analogy, but not perfect. Using one gets you more speed, the other (should be) easier. Both do have pros/cons. Also, asking which to learn is an important question. You have to use one or the other.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more focused, and in particular make it less of a "where do I start" question, since those aren't appropriate here.

Comment: Also, there isn't *really* such a thing as "proper memory management" in a language-agnostic sense. There is the kind of memory/resource management you have to do in C++, and there is the kind you have to do in C# (just because you have a GC doesn't mean you can pretend you have infinite memory). You can learn just as much about general resource management techniques in C# as in C++; I wouldn't consider that a compelling reason to bother to learn. Both are abstractions over reality anyhow.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and making it more focused. It is interesting that you say there is no such thing as proper memory management.

Comment: "Which technology to use" questions are now [off topic](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good) here, as well as the fact that "which is easier" is a bit of a subjective question.

Comment: While It is subjective, there are still lots of facts that deserve a post. Because this is closed, my response here http://pastebin.com/RcVFRVm5

Comment: @Tetrad I vote for this to be reopened, if anything because I find the answer given by xoofx to be quite interesting and deserving of being preserved.

Comment: @DavidGouveia Closed questions still exist until/unless they are deleted.

Comment: @Noctrine I am aware, but it is a shame that xoofx's answer will remain as a pastebin on a comment then because he wasn't fast enough to post it.

Comment: @DavidGouveia, I agree and this is annoying as I wrote my answer while in the mean time this question was closed. I don't think that the current policy to systematically close a question that could potentially lead to uninteresting point of view is helping here. The original question was not "Should I use A or B?" but was a bit more subtle like "B is wrapping A, but at a first glance, It appears that it is easier to use A directly. What is the point of B?". This question is typically a problem that a game programmer could face.

Comment: @xoofx Thank you for that wonderful and in depth answer. If this question is ever opened, please add it and I will mark it as the best answer. It really is a shame you can't get any rep boost or any real credit for such a great answer.

Comment: @Tetrad I truly believe that xoofx's answer would be an asset to this site and would like to see this question reopened so he can add it. Holding this question closed does a lot less good for this site than allowing such a thorough and well written response to comprehensively answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not a huge C++ fan, then the question I have is, are you already competent at C#? Any way you slice it, DirectX and its related APIs are fairly complex and you will get stuck in some places if this is your first time using a 3D graphics API. Because they are merely wrappers, they involve low-level stuff that you have to deal with on your own. If you decide you want something a bit higher-level than SlimDX or SharpDX, XNA may be another option for you, but at the trade-off that it's limited to Direct3D 9-level graphics.

The best thing, in my opinion, about using a managed D3D wrapper is that you don't have to really worry about memory leaks! The only major performance profiling you'll have to do is GPU efficiency (obviously) and garbage collection rate.

Comment: I guess the answer to the question on competency would depend on what you mean by competent. I certainly wouldn't call myself an expert, but I would probably guess that I am competent. When you say "low-level stuff that you have to deal with on your own," do you mean DirectX related things (buffers, models, shaders, etc) or more generally C++ related things (memory management, pointers, etc)?

Comment: When I mentioned low-level stuff, I mean the stuff that is usually pertinent to most graphics APIs, so basically  handling buffers, shaders, API render states, etc.

Answer (score 4):

As APIs, SlimDX and SharpDX are almost exactly as difficult to use as the native D3D API or any other APIs they encapsulate. With a few minor exceptions, any ease-of-use benefit you get from either API comes primarily from the fact that you're using a higher level language (C#). This is because, as Martins points out in the comments on your question, they're both lightweight wrappers.

Comment: This is about what I was seeing. So, do you think it would be easier to learn DirectX (knowing I don't know much C++) or SharpDX (knowing there seem to be very few tutorials for it)?